# How to call javascript function only once during window.onscroll event?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getH4() {
    var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName('bucket_left');
    for(var i=0;i<xyz.length;i++){
        var x=document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[i].innerHTML;
        var current_bucket = xyz[i];
        var y=current_bucket.firstChild.href;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+y+"\">"+x+"</a>";
        newdiv.className = "hover_title_h4";
        current_bucket.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}

window.onscroll=getH4;
```

In above code i want to append new `div` in set of `div`s having class `bucket_left` and this `div`s generated from infinite scrolling. above code is working fine but on scroll it appends so many `div`s. 
so how do i append only once ?

Comment: Consider defining a global boolean variable that is set to initially to `false` and when the first scroll happens is set to `true`. Call the function only if the variable is `false`.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line at the end of your function:

```
function getH4() {
    // ...

    window.onscroll = null;
}
```

Comment: its working but only for 1st set of `div`s which generated when 1st `onscroll` happens. after 2nd `onscroll` its not appending `div` at all.

Comment: @PoojaDesai Yes, but that's exactly what you wanted to achieve: `... code is working fine but on scroll it appends so many divs. so how do i append only once ?`.

Comment: @PoojaDesai: well that is the requirement i suppose. You dont want further divs to be added on next scroll!!!

Comment: initally it is adding so many `div`s in same `div` having class `bucket_left`. what i want is to add only one `div` in that particular `div` having class`bucket_left`.
but function `getH4()` should call next `onscroll` event, so that it append `div` for upcoming or next set of `div` having class `bucket_left` generated from infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

create a global boolean variable and set it to false. again set it to true in the window scroll event and chk the variable is false using a if block. put your code inside that if block.

```
var isScrolled = false;

function getH4() {
    if(!isScrolled){
        //your code
    }
    isScrolled = true
}
```

Comment: its working but only for 1st set of `div`s which generated when 1st `onscroll` happens. after 2nd `onscroll` its not appending `div` at all.

Comment: what did you meant by second `onscroll`

Comment: What happen is when you scroll for the first time code inside the `onscroll` event will execute. When you try to scroll again that condition becomes true and code will not execute inside the if condition.

Comment: yes you are right, code will not execute because of if condition but what i want is to execute code for next `oncsroll` so that code will append `div` for next set `div`s generated from infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to set the `onscroll` property to none as following at the end of you JavaScript function:

```
window.onscroll = null;
```

Now when the script executes for the first time, it will perform its function and the above line will set the `onscroll` to null and thus will not invoke any event on scroll of your mouse and so your function wont be invoked again and again on the event except for the first time.

Or you could handle it logically by setting a public var say `var check = 0` and then set the variable to 1 when entered for the first time. So you need to check the value of `check` and based on that execute the function

```
var check = 1;
function getH4() {
    if(check==1)
    {
    var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName('bucket_left');
    for(var i=0;i<xyz.length;i++){
        var x=document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[i].innerHTML;
        var current_bucket = xyz[i];
        var y=current_bucket.firstChild.href;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+y+"\">"+x+"</a>";
        newdiv.className = "hover_title_h4";
        current_bucket.appendChild(newdiv);
     }
        check=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: initally it is adding so many divs in same `div` having class `bucket_left`. what i want is to add only one `div` in that particular `div` having class `bucket_left`. but function `getH4()` should call next `onscroll` event, so that it append `div` for upcoming or next set of `div` having class `bucket_left` generated from infinite scrolling.

Comment: @PoojaDesai: Here is wat i get, u need to add exactly "ONE" div in a scroll (a scroll may contain scrolling more than one time)..am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
when scrolling,the check equal false, and the append event will happen just once;
when the scroll end(mouseup or mouseout), the check equal true, you can append again.

```
var check = true;
function getH4(event) {
    event.target.onmouseup = function() {
        check = true;
    }
    event.target.onmouseout = function() {
        check = true;
    }
    if (check) {
        var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName('bucket_left');
        for(var i=0;i<xyz.length;i++){
            var x=document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[i].innerHTML;
            var current_bucket = xyz[i];
            var y=current_bucket.firstChild.href;
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+y+"\">"+x+"</a>";
            newdiv.className = "hover_title_h4";
            current_bucket.appendChild(newdiv);
        }
    check = false;
}

window.onscroll=getH4
```